# How do I return a specific substring within a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, strsplit

I have a column of text that I need to find the substring and return the whole word, but can't figure out how to get the entire word.

Each column has text with a coding at the bottom labelled "ATT03", "ATT04" etc and I want to take that ATT and make a new column of each of the labels.

So for example my column looks like this:

blahblahblah text [ATT03]: blahblahblah

blahblahblah text [ATT03]: blahblahblah

blahblahblah text [ATT04]: blahblahbblahblah

blah text [ATT08]: blahblahblah

```
df_att=(df2.loc[:,'Report Text'].str.split("ATT",1)).str[-1]
```

I used this to create a new column, but it only splits the data into "ATT08: blahblahblahblah", and I really only want the ATT in between the "[]". I don't need all the extraneous data.

Is there regular expression/code that would return just the ATT03? without the rest of the string around it?

Thank you so much! I've been struggling through this for hours and am frustrated.

Comment: use `str.extract("(ATT[^\]]*)")` i think ...

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very close. It gives me the characters before the ATT though. " ATTENDING PHYSICIAN AGREEMENT [ATT03" is the input I got out.

Comment: try `str.extract("\[(ATT[^\]]*)")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
df_att=(df2.loc[:,'Report Text'].str.extract("\[(ATT[^\]]*)")
```

It will extract the text between the brackets that you are looking for.

Comment: @JLondon: please mark the question as answered / answer as accepted.